# On azure Event bus How much times takes from a letter go to a dead letter queue

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, event-bus

I'm testing an implementation of a retry policy of azure event bus, and my question is how much time after, a letter will go to the dead letter queue.

Thanks

Comment: You mean Azure Service Bus or Azure Event Hub?

Comment: I mean Azure Service Bus ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding when a message will be deadlettered, it's not a matter of time. It actually depends on 2 user configurable properties:

1. **Number of times message has been dequeued**: This is a property you define at the Queue level (or Subscription level in case of Topics & Subscription). Once a message has been dequeued that many times, it will be deadlettered. You control this by specifying appropriate value for [`MaxDeliveryCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount?view=azure-dotnet) property for a queue.
2. **Should the message be deadlettered on expiration**: Again, this is a property you define a queue level (or Subscription level in case of Topics & Subscription). If this property is set to true and message time-to-live (TTL) has expired, then the message will be deadlettered instead of being removed. You control this by specifying true/false for [`EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.enabledeadletteringonmessageexpiration?view=azure-dotnet) property.

For Topics & Subscription, there's another way to deadletter a message and that is to set true to `deadletter a message when there's an exception in filter expression evaluation` property on a Subscription. You control this by specifying true/false for [`EnableDeadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptiondescription.enabledeadletteringonfilterevaluationexceptions?view=azure-dotnet) property.